# box.get_top() and array.get() in real time?

Tags: pine-script

I would like the count of pips be done in real time but it's only done on the bar close. Is it possible to have `(GetBoxTopValue_t - GetBoxBotomValue_t)` in real time ?

```
    t = 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(bricks) - 1
        GetBoxTopValue_t = box.get_top(array.get(bricks,i - t))
        GetBoxBotomValue_t = box.get_bottom(array.get(bricks,i - t))
        if barstate.islast
            box.set_text(array.get(bricks,i-t), ' ' + str.tostring(GetBoxTopValue_t - GetBoxBotomValue_t) + ' pips.')
```

EDIT :

Yet the box.delete and array.delete works well in real time.

```
        if high >= GetBoxTopValue_t and low <= GetBoxBotomValue_t
            box.delete(array.get(bricks,i - t))
            array.remove(bricks,i - t)
            t := t + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `strategy()` declaration has a `calc_on_every_tick` parameter:

> **calc_on_every_tick (const bool)** Specifies whether the strategy should be recalculated on each realtime tick. If true, when the strategy is running on a realtime bar, it will recalculate on each chart update. If false, the strategy only calculates when the realtime bar closes. The argument used does not affect strategy calculation on historical data. This setting can also be changed in the strategy's "Settings/Properties" tab. Optional. The default is false.

Keep in mind that it will run ALL of your code on each tick, so it might break other things. You can't ask it to run only on specific part of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried but it didn't solve the problem. The subtraction is done in close and not in real time. Yet the box.delete and array.delete works well in real time.

Answer (score 0):

You're calculating based on the state of a bar, I'm assuming to avoid re-painting, so try using if barstate.isrealtime or if that doesn't work, barstate.isnew.
Another alternative is to use the negative: if not barstate.ishistory

Comment: Thanks Greg, Strangely, only barstate.isnew works (i've not tried it in real time), the others remove the text and the colors of the boxes, I'm still working on it,